# How to validate single letter domain names with regex?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, email

I'm trying to create a validation rule using Regex, for my C# MVC Model.

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\w[-._+\w]*\w@\w{1,}.\w{2,3})", ErrorMessage = "* Email Address: Please enter a valid Email Address.")]
public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

This Regex works for everything except single letter domains.

Here's a live preview, how can I create a regex for this use case?

http://regex101.com/r/bA6gU9

Comment: So, your example shows it matching the ones you want except for the +. Would `[\w+]+@[\w]{1,}+\.[\w]{1,}` not work?

Comment: Emailaddress validation is rather pointless beyond a single dot. Everything else is optional, depending on the circumstances. You would be easier off just trying to send an email and seeing if it succeeds. Right now you'll have a bunch of false negatives from people who pimp their emailaddress.

Comment: Could you please explain your criteria for a valid email address? I don't understand why the handle part of the email address needs to be a single word character, followed by any number of characters from the character set, followed by a single word character. This pattern doesn't seem to match the emails that you require to be valid (eg. `+sd@gmail.com`, which you claim should be valid, isn't valid according to your criteria)

Comment: 100% agree with you @JeroenVannevel, however the client wants what the client wants. :) I have to make due with the best I have at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example, this would work:

```
[\w+.]+@\w+\.[\w.]+
```

http://regex101.com/r/zL2aI3

**Matches:**

- tes.t@gmail.co.uk
- q@q.com
- a+2@gmail.com
- +sd@gmail.com
- a++abc@gmail.com

**Non-matches:**

- ·$(")@gmail.com
- (((@q.com

And really, in the end, all you really care about is that there's an `@` and a `.`. Past that, [just send it](http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)!

Comment: This works on the regex101 website, but on my actual MVC code it's saying: `parsing "([\w+\.]+@[\w]{1,}+\.[\w]{1,})" - Nested quantifier +.`

Comment: @Serg, try the following `[\w+.]+@\w{1,}\.[\w.]{1,}`

Comment: Oh, no it's complaining about the {1,}+ -- remove the {1,} entirely

Comment: Simplified: `[\w+\.]+@\w+\.[\w\.]+`

Comment: @r3mus You don't have to escape the dot inside the character class.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is example you are looking for:

> **`([\w-\.+]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})`**

i got all matched that need to be and not matched last two.

Comment: this will also match underscores and dashes and dots in part before @ and domains like domain.com and also name.domain.com in part after @

Answer (score 0):

Cheap and nasty with no regex:

```
    try
    {
        new MailAddress(emailAddress);

    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        // not valid
    }
```